# How to transfer data between tables, only where id does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I need to copy a set of data from TableA into TableB, like so:

```
INSERT INTO TableB(id,field1,field2) 
SELECT id,field1,field2 FROM TableA
```

The above will work well, however `TableB` might already contain some of the records which I need to copy, identified by the PK `id`.

Thus, how can I add a clause to **only** insert a record if that `id` value is not already in TableB? I know a `WHERE` clause can be added at the end of the INSERT statement, but I am unsure of how to apply it for each and every record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look for 3 methods comparing [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).

> The best way to search for missing values in *MySQL* is using a *LEFT*
>   *JOIN* / *IS NULL* or *NOT IN* rather than *NOT EXISTS*.

---

You can use [NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).

```
INSERT INTO TableB (id, field1, field2) 
SELECT id, field1, field2 
FROM TableA t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT *
                   FROM TableB t2
                   WHERE t1.id = t2.id
                  )
```

---

Also you can use [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html).

```
INSERT INTO TableB (id, field1, field2) 
SELECT id, field1, field2 
FROM TableA t1
LEFT JOIN TableB t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

---

Also you can use [NOT IN](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php).

```
INSERT INTO TableB (id, field1, field2) 
SELECT id, field1, field2 
FROM TableA t1
WHERE t1.id NOT IN (
                    SELECT t2.id 
                    FROM TableB t2 
                    WHERE t1.id = t2.id
                   )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - does this have better performance than the other options mentioned in the other answers?

Comment: Check my updated answer here are link with comparing 3 methods that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join as below

```
INSERT INTO TableB(id,field1,field2) 
SELECT id,field1,field2 FROM TableA 
left join TableB on TableB.id = TableA.id
where TableB.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want a where clause with exists()

```
INSERT INTO TableB(id,field1,field2) 
SELECT id,field1,field2 FROM TableA a
WHERE  not exists (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE a.id = b.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - does this have better performance than the other options mentioned in the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TableB(id,field1,field2)     
SELECT A.id,A.field1,A.field2 FROM TableA WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT B.ID FROM TABLEB WHERE B.ID = A.ID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - does this have better performance than the other options mentioned in the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a left join:

```
INSERT INTO TableB(id,field1,field2) 
SELECT id,field1,field2 FROM TableA left join TableB on tableA.id = tableb.id where tablea.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use **set operator  EXCEPT** for best performance as below:

here it will take two sets of data the  it goes for minus and gives output

```
INSERT INTO TableB(id,field1,field2) (
SELECT id,field1,field2 FROM TableA 
 except
SELECT id,field1,field2 FROM TableB )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - does this have better performance than the other options mentioned in the other answers?

Comment: yes @guru as per I Know that each and every time where will executes and hits cache leads to low performance.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO TableB(id,field1,field2) 
SELECT T2.id,T2.field1,T2.field2 FROM TableA as T1 
inner join TableB as T2 on T1.id <> T2.id